# Etymology of the idiom "what with"

Tags: etymology, idiom-meaning

I'm curious about the etymology of the idiom ***what with***. How did it come to mean *Taking into consideration; because of*?

> You say *what with* in order to introduce the reasons for a particular situation, especially an undesirable one.

*What with one thing and another, it was fairly late in the day when we returned to Shrewsbury.*

[*Collins*]

Sometimes it's rather easy to parse an idiom to get to its meaning, something the route an idiom takes traces back to cultural influences, and so forth.

I couldn't find any reliable source listing the etymology of this idiom, nor is it forthright clear as to why the idiom should mean what it means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a hint on [phrases.org](https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/62/messages/170.html):

> It is a *construction in use in English since the **Middle Ages***: it means "in consequence of, on account of, as a result of; in view of, considering (one thing and another)".
> Centuries ago English people also said "*What through...*" and "*What for...*" which meant the same thing; but these expressions are now obsolete.

But that's too vague for my taste, so let's dig deeper. *[Grammarphobia](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2016/06/what-with.html)* has more information about the parsing of such structures:

> This construction has a folksy, contemporary sound, but it’s neither. It’s been around since the ***Middle Ages*** and appears in the most elevated writing.
>
> Here ***“what” is used to introduce an adverbial phrase*** that starts with a preposition, and the preposition is generally “with.”

About its origin timewise, the site says

> This use of “what” has been around since the **1100s**, the OED says, although in the very earliest examples the preposition was “*for*,” as in this quotation from the *Lambeth Homilies* (circa 1175), a collection of Old English sermons:
>
> > Alle we beoð in monifald wawe ine þisse wreche liue, ***hwat for*** ure eldere werkes, ***hwat for*** ure aȝene gultes. (“*We are all in manifold woe in this wretched life, what for our elders’ deeds, what for our own guilts*”).

The actual phrase we are looking into, ***what with***:

> began showing up in English writing in the ***15th century***, the OED says. The dictionary’s earliest example is from a **1476** letter that John Paston wrote from Calais to his family back home in Norfolk:
>
> > I ame some-whatt crased [ill], whatwyth the see [sea] and what wythe thys dyet [diet] heere.

Now, how and why this expression has come to mean what it means is not explained in the sources I have found, although the Grammarphobia's parsing and the other original forms of the phrase shed some light. It may be related to the fact that Old English ***hwæt*** used to also mean ***why***:

> Old English *hwæt*, referring to things in abstraction; also "***why***, ***wherefore***; indeed, surely, truly," ([Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=what))